# Modify JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have an issue with a JTextField in Java.
It's works on Linux Ubuntu but not on Mac Os.

I can't modify a JtextFieldValue when I click on it. 
[image: Impossible to modify JTextField]

This is my function to create a popup with the JText Field :

```
    protected void createPopup(String popUpText, JPanel panelContent,JList<String> jList,JTextField jTextField,String msg){
    if(popup!=null){
        buttons.remove(this.controller.getOK_SAUVEGARDE());
        popup.hide();
    }
    JPanel panelPopup;
    if(msg!=null)
        panelPopup = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    else
        panelPopup = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
    JLabel labelPopup = new JLabel(popUpText);
    panelPopup.add(labelPopup);
    if(jTextField!=null){
        jTextField.setEditable(true);
        textPopup = jTextField;
        buttons.put(this.controller.getOK_SAUVEGARDE(), createButton(this.controller.getOK_SAUVEGARDE()));
        panelPopup.add(textPopup);
        panelPopup.add(buttons.get(this.controller.getOK_SAUVEGARDE()));
    }else if (jList!=null){
        niveauList = jList;
        buttons.put(this.controller.getOK_LOAD(), createButton(this.controller.getOK_LOAD()));
        panelPopup.add(niveauList);
        panelPopup.add(buttons.get(this.controller.getOK_LOAD()));
    }else if(msg != null){
        JLabel gameOverText = new JLabel(msg);
        panelPopup.add(gameOverText);
        panelPopup.add(buttons.get(this.controller.getMENU_BUTTON()));
    }
    if(msg==null){
        buttons.put(this.controller.getQUITTER_POPUP(),createButton(this.controller.getQUITTER_POPUP()));
        panelPopup.add(buttons.get(this.controller.getQUITTER_POPUP()));
    }

    PopupFactory popupFactory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
    popup = popupFactory.getPopup(panelContent, panelPopup,this.controller.getMyFrame().getWidth()/2,this.controller.getMyFrame().getHeight()/4);
    popup.show();
}
```

This how I call it :

```
createPopup("Nom du niveau ",panelRight,null,new JTextField("Nom de la sauvegarde",14),null);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question / problem. Is there any exception occuring? What is the expected behaviour? Whats happening? Can you redruce your code to the most simple core so we can compile & test it ourselves?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
The problem is that i can't modify the content of my JTextField.
For exemple, I would like to change "Nom de la sauvegarde" with anything (not in java code, but when i'm using my program), but when I click on it I can't write an other text. On linux it works and I have no idea why.

Comment: I've never seen something like this happening...

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No exception...
It's a big mistake